# What is Mathematica for?

Tags: raspbian, software-recommendation

I recently started looking into the pre-installed programs that come with Raspbian,and I saw Mathematica.  I opened it and it was some sort of terminal. My question is what is the use of this program? If it just does math could you not use a C++ library or something? I could not find any useful examples or explanations in my searches that a C++ or Python script could not do already. Could someone shed some light on the use of this program?

Comment: Q.v. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I certainly did not know there was a SE for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find [Symbolic Computation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html) to be *rather* difficult in Python or C++. F'rinstance:

```
$ wolfram 
Wolfram Language (Raspberry Pi Pilot Release)
Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research
Information & help: wolfram.com/raspi

In[1]:= Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x]                                               

               -1 + 2 x
        ArcTan[--------]                             2
               Sqrt[3]     Log[1 + x]   Log[1 - x + x ]
Out[1]= ---------------- + ---------- - ---------------
            Sqrt[3]            3               6
```

Yeah, Mathematica just integrated a function there.

Answer (score 3):

**What is the use of Mathematica?**

Ok, so Mathematica is quite a powerful tool for computational mathematics. The list of its [features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) is too long to be repeated here. While coming from symbolic computation it was developed to include significant functionality in numerical mathematics, statistics, visualization and so on and so on. It's not for no reason called one of the major general purpose computational algebra systems.

**Could you not just use a c++ library or something?**

Depending on the task at hand there are of course alternatives available - some of them are freeware not just on the Pi. See this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems#Functionality) for a comparison of functionalities of computational algebra systems. I'd also like to point to this [thread for alternatives to mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/alternatives-to-mathematica) which covers many aspects. To name just one: [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/).

If you just want to do some number crunching in your programs or script have a look at [SciPy (with NumPy & SymPy)](http://www.scipy.org/) that offers already a broad set of tools for scientific computing, symbolic mathematics and plotting.